# Offset position of instances with regard to proximity and direction of another object using geometry nodes simulation?

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I'm experimenting with the new simulation geometry nodes and I'm trying to make a grid of instances that will move out of the way of an object in the direction they're being pushed. Currently, my node set up works but only if the pushing object originates within the grid. If the object starts from outside the grid, it "sucks" the instances out instead of pushing them in (this effect also occurs at the center of the grid).

This image is when the ball originates inside, it works as intended and pushes instances away
[image: Object starting inside grid and pushing out]

Here, as the ball approaches the borders it "sucks in" in the instances and spits them out behind the ball instead of pushing them into the grid
[image: When object enters grid it forces the objects outward instead on in]

Here is my node set up. I am also trying to find a way for the instances to slowly go back to their original positions after being offset but that's a whole other issue
[image: Node set up]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is example of checking if points are inside a collision mesh, placing points at closes mesh surface and moving points back to the original place.

[image]

[image]

[image]